# Trying to match and modify part of a line in awk or sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I tried several sintaxes (sed/awk) to add a suffix at the end of specific lines that contains "ltm virtual /Common/" before "{" (its a bigip platform > bigip.conf) but Im not expert using it..

I got these lines at the file:

```
ltm virtual /Common/VS_exemple_80 {

ltm virtual /Common/VS_exemple_443 {

ltm virtual /Common/VS_test_80 {

ltm virtual /Common/VS_test_443 {
```

I do need to add XX at the end, like this:

```
ltm virtual /Common/VS_exemple_80_XX {

ltm virtual /Common/VS_exemple_443_XX {

ltm virtual /Common/VS_test_80_XX {

ltm virtual /Common/VS_test_443_XX {
```

Note that all lines that I need to perform this change starts with:

```
ltm virtual /Common/VS_XXXXX
```

What I tried to do is found the line "ltm virtual", run from VS_ to the end of the line "{" and append "_XX"

Thank you guys..

I tried:

```
sed -i '/^ltm virtual/s/[^ ]*$/&_XX/' bigip.conf.bkp
```

I can match the correct lines, but the suffix is append at the end of line..

```
ltm virtual /Common/VS_test_80 {_XX
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us what you have tried.

Comment: Hi Andy, I tried:
sed -i '/^ltm virtual/s/[^ ]*$/&_XX/' bigip.conf.bkp

I cant match the correct lines with "/^ltm virtual/" but the _XX is insert at the end of line..

Comment: @EdMorton I already updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` at the end of your regexp is anchoring it to the end of the line and therefore making it not match any string in  the input, plus you're trying to use `/`s in a regexp that's delimited by `/`s and you can't do that - when trying to match the regexp `a/b` in sed, instead of `/a/b/` you have to escape the `/` like `/a\/b/` or more concisely just use a different delimiter, e.g. `:a/b:`.

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's:ltm virtual /Common/[^ ]*:&_XX:' file
ltm virtual /Common/VS_exemple_80_XX {

ltm virtual /Common/VS_exemple_443_XX {

ltm virtual /Common/VS_test_80_XX {

ltm virtual /Common/VS_test_443_XX {
```

Answer (score 2):

You are matching the entire line, and then adding `_XX` at the end. You need to only match part of the line up to the `{`.

```
sed -r 's/^ltm virtual \/Common\/VS_\w+/&_XX/'
```

Note that the `\w+` (one or more word characters) requires extended regular expressions, since you need the `-r`.